# Проблема с gradle 4.1 и кириллицей в имени пользователя

Tags: android-studio, windows-10, кириллица, android-gradle

Здравствуйте. После обновления gradle до версии 4.1 рабочий проект перестал собираться со следующей ошибкой:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.
> Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
```

Причина ошибки:

```
C:\Users\???????\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\mmedia-6.4.0.aar\797ef4880c05b0dda9bcadb3925fb17a\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\mmadsdk_play.png: error: file not found.
```

Если я верно понимаю, это следствие кириллицы в имени пользователя Windows. Как известно, в Windows 10 проблематично сменить имя пользователя. Есть ли альтернативные методы решения проблемы?

Comment: На будущее: кириллица в пути -- это геморрой (и не только для Gradle).

Comment: Я понимаю, но за 2 года использования windows 10 для разработки ПО в различных IDE столкнулся с проблемой только после обновления gradle